# Alsaequal does not affect my sound - Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, lubuntu, alsa

I have a problem with alsa equalizer plugin on my lubuntu installation. I managed to install it (not without problems), but it does not seem to affect the sound output. I purged pulseaudio, which had the working equalizer, but was stopping to work after a couple of days and I had to reinstall it, which was kind of a bummer. My .asoundrc file looks like this:

```
ctl.equal {
  type equal;
}

pcm.plugequal {
  type equal;
  # Modify the line below if you don't
  # want to use sound card 0.
  #slave.pcm "plug:dmix";
}

 pcm.equal {
  # Or if you want the equalizer to be your
  # default soundcard uncomment the following
  # line and comment the above line.
#pcm.!default {
  type plug;
  slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

I think it might be related to my soundcard configuration, but I probably won't figure it out on my own. Also, I searched the site for the same question, and could only find this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/alsaequal-runs-but-sliders-do-not-seem-to-affect-audio , but there was no real help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this `sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio  pulseaudio-utils`
after that restart the computer and test it out
It worked for me!